# Socket Client - how to

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I am in an Android project which uses Bluetooth sockets. The app is the client socket. But the app crashes when working. Can anyone help me in solving the issue.

here is the code

```
public class READ extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String btAdress = "00:10:60:D1:95:CD";
    BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);
    }
    public void ConnectThread(View v){
        BluetoothDevice device;
        device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(btAdress);
        ConnectT(device);
    }
    public void ConnectT(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        String uuid = "a60f35f0-b93a-11de-8a39-08002009c666";
        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(uuid));
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException nullException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the logcat. There you will see the exception that causes the crash.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) { }` Oh oh you are doing nothing! You should at least have `e.printStackTrace()` there. And a log statements that prints `e.getMessage()`.   And further you should take action if you catch an exception.  You now continue with your code as if nothing has happened. Better return. Adapt all your catch blocks.

Comment: `public void ConnectThread(View v)` ?? A public function in an Activity? Oh oh Where and how are you calling it? Or is it assigned to a button in xml?